# проблемы с $_GET в php

Tags: php, get

Есть код который принимает значение из ссылки и сравнивает его с значениями из базы.
Есть ссылка которая содержит в себе информацию о значениях.
Пример.
http://sitename.com/user/auth_mobile.php?nick=Dimitri%0D&password=Dimitry2018
(Эта ссылка генерируется в Flash "AS3") и не проходит проверку. Сразу сообщу - нет никаких ограничений по символам.
http://sitename.com/user/auth_mobile.php?nick=Dimitri&password=Dimitry2018
Достаточно убрать лишние знаки и всё заработает (но запрос из flash изменить нельзя)

Понять не могу, что делать. Как быть - чем лечить, пытался взрывать лишние значения после $_GET - не помогло.

Проверил оба запроса в Fiddler и обнаружил что значение %0D добавляет пустое значение с новой строки. Как от него можно избавиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в php есть куча возможностей для обработки строк. Просто почитайте как кодируются спецсимволы (которым является перевод строки) в URI-формате - это знак % и двухбайтное шестнадцатиричное число. Т.е. вы можете просто поискать все вхождения символа % в массив $_GET и исключить сам символ % и два байта после него.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!